# Load report failed, If put SQL Command in place otherwise FormLoad

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, crystal-reports-2010

I have CrystalReport page, The below code is just load one time through FormLoad and by using !Page.IsPostBack and If I try to reload it again give me error "Load report failed."

```
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [tbJournals]", cnn);
        cnn.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable("tbl");
        da.Fill(dt);
        cnn.Close();

        _rdStudents = new ReportDocument();
        _rdStudents.Load(Server.MapPath("~\\Accounting\\Journal_Report.rpt"));
        _rdStudents.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "password", ".\\SQLEXPRESS", "GoldenDeveloper");
        _rdStudents.SetDataSource(dt);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = _rdStudents;
        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
     }
```

But What I want to do put this code under CommandButton to change in search variable to make SQL Statement for example like that

```
SELECT * FROM [tbJournals] where [Date] = '"+ txtDate.Text +"'
```

But once I put the code instead of FormLoad to CommandButton give me error "Load report failed."

Thanks In Advance ....

Answer (score 0):

I think the next time, when you reload then the

```
(!IsPostBack)
{
//This works only when the first time page loads.
}
```

So the code written in the same will not get executed.Try to write the code in Page_Load and after this function
like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [tbJournals]", cnn);
cnn.Open();
da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
dt = new DataTable("tbl");
da.Fill(dt);
cnn.Close();

_rdStudents = new ReportDocument();
_rdStudents.Load(Server.MapPath("~\\Accounting\\Journal_Report.rpt"));
_rdStudents.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "password", ".\\SQLEXPRESS", "GoldenDeveloper");
_rdStudents.SetDataSource(dt);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = _rdStudents;
CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

Comment: I using "!IsPostBack" because if I didn't and put it direct in FormLoad once I make refresh to page will give me error "Load report failed." My problem is the code load in page one time only else give me error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved finally, The problem was in report path, I did "CrystalReportViewer" report path blank and putted the report path like that `_rdStudents.Load(Server.MapPath("Journal_Report.rpt"));`  by using Server.MapPath